# Finite subgroups of the General Linear Group

Tags: linear-algebra

Let G be a finite subgroup of GLn(K) where K is an algebraic closure of Q, the rational Field. Prove that every element of G is diagonalisable over K. For solving this, I understand that an element of G is diagonalisable iff its minimal polynomial is square free. I know that all eigen values are in K but how do I ensure that the Arithmetic multiplicity of every eigen value is equal to its Geometric multiplicity? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it suffices to consider finite order $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$. This being the case, $A^m = I$ for some $m$. Therefore the minimal polynomial for $A$ must divide the square-free polynomial $x^m - 1$, which makes the minimal polynomial square-free as well.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you. Got it.